# Google Cloud Language in Google Colab fails since yesterday

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-cloud-language

I have problems since yesterday running Google Cloud NLP entity analysis in Google Colab. I'm using almost exactly this code https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-analysis-client-libraries?hl=en#analyze_some_text

I get either the error

> module 'google.cloud.language_v1' has no attribute 'Document'

If I install google-cloud-language using

```
!pip install --upgrade --quiet google-cloud-language
```

I get the error

> AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'api_audience'

I was workin 2 days ago. So I wonder if something has changed in either colab or google.cloud.language_v1???

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
> all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
> the following dependency conflicts. tensorflow
> 2.8.2+zzzcolab20220527125636 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible. google-cloud-translate
> 1.5.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.6.0, but you have google-api-core 2.8.2 which is incompatible. google-cloud-firestore
> 1.7.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.8.2 which is incompatible. google-cloud-datastore
> 1.8.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.6.0, but you have google-api-core 2.8.2 which is incompatible. google-cloud-core 1.0.3
> requires google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have
> google-api-core 2.8.2 which is incompatible. firebase-admin 4.4.0
> requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0;
> platform_python_implementation != "PyPy", but you have google-api-core
> 2.8.2 which is incompatible.

Comment: What version of google-cloud-language is being installed? I tried with standard pip install and it installed google_cloud_language 2.5.1. And Document is there.

Comment: How do you get the version print(language_v1.__version__) wasn't working for me?

Comment: try !pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language (without the quiet)

Comment: its also 2.5.1. now I see a error message. Added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older version works

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language==2.4.3
```